# Want a textView or textField in Native Script XML without bottom border

Tags: nativescript

The default textbox has a bottom border.
How can I get a textView or textField in Native Script XML without that bottom border?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the suggestion by Nikolay, the following should do it in the stylesheet

```
background-color: transparent;
border-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Just setting `background-color: transparent` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

One possible decision could be to remove textfield and textview border-bottom is to set background color. This will color up the border too. I will give you an example bellow

**main-page.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
  <StackLayout backgroundColor="red">
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"/>
    <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" />
    <Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true"/>
    <TextField hint="" id="tfield" text="tests textfield"/>
   <TextView hint="" id="tview" text="tests textView" editable="true" style="border-color:white; "  />


  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**main-page.js**

```
   var main_view_model_1 = require("./main-view-model");
var color_1 = require('color');
// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
function navigatingTo(args) {
    // Get the event sender
    var page = args.object;
    var tf = page.getViewById("tfield");
    tf.borderColor = new color_1.Color("#ffffff");
    tf.backgroundColor = new color_1.Color(100, 255, 0, 0);
    var tv = page.getViewById("tview");
    tv.borderColor = new color_1.Color("#ffffff");
    tv.backgroundColor = new color_1.Color(100, 255, 0, 0);
    page.bindingContext = new main_view_model_1.HelloWorldModel();
}
exports.navigatingTo = navigatingTo;
```

Comment: You posted 2 times the same code, please correct your main-page.js

Comment: yes, this should be applicable for your project, Regarding to the topic you  setting 
`TextField, TextView {background:transparent;}` in your `CSS` should also remove the border. In case you would like to change the color of blue underline in the TextField you could find workaround here -https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/550#issuecomment-244930597